# tools to determine memory leak in a c/c++ code

Tags: c++, c, unix, memory-leaks

On the unix environment, are there any tools which can easily analyse the code and mention there is a chance of memory leakage in certain sections of the code.
HPUX/AIX/Solaris

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're talking about [static analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) then there's [cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page) (among many others)

If you're talking about a [runtime checker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_program_analysis) (which will be way more accurate and reliable than static analysis) there's [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

There's loads of other tools available.  Check out the links above for more information

[Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/?S_TACT=105AGY59&S_CMP=09&ca=dtl-0903) will work on AIX (though it's not free.

HP has the [wdb](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801/?ciid=29080f1bace021100f1bace02110275d6e10RCRD) debugger, and it's capable of detecting memory leaks.

Comment: i think valgrind can only be used on LINUX .not on HPUX or AIX which have no GUI.

Comment: @wvwvwv, 2 points, 1, Hpux, Aix, etc, all support GUI's of one form or another.  2, valgrind is a command line tool (no gui)

Comment: @wvwvwv, you are correct about valgrind not supporting HPUX or AIX directly.  You could try porting it yourself though this wouldn't be easy I suspect

Comment: valgrind's supported platforms are listed here: http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html

Comment: @wvwvwv I've added some AIX and HP compatible products

Comment: gperftools from google is pretty good at finding my memory leaks and is a bit less invasive than valgrind

Comment: thanks for mentioning ab purify.i have used wdb but it works like a normal debugger like gdb but will have GUI.i have used wdb on solaris. but not on hp

Answer (score 1):

I use Insure and it works well. For more information use
http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/article.jsp?articleId=530

Answer (score 0):

Although not a specialized tool for detecting memory leaks another option is the [Boehm-Demers-Weiser garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) available from HP Labs.

It works as a replacement for new and malloc.

[Here](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/leak.html) are instructions to use it as a leak detector. It is, or was, used by Mozilla as a leak detector for Firefox. If i recall correctly it was also used by Mono and DotGNU Portable.NET as a gc.

Answer (score 0):

I also use this tool regularly and it has solved many problems for me instantly.
This is one  tool which I have created for identifying memory leaks in solaris unix.
[Here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/11/finding-memory-leaks-on-solaris-is-no.html) it is. The way to run it also mentioned [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/11/finding-memory-leaks-on-solaris-is-no.html) clearly.