# how to check memory leaks in a c++ code. Are there any free tool for checking memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

how to check memory leaks in a c++  code. Are there any free tool for checking memory leaks

Comment: For UNIX or UNIX-like systems (e.g. OSX, BSD, Linux), there's [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: For Windows, read e.g. [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx).

Comment: Depending on the platform, this might be a duplicate of either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195220/tools-to-determine-memory-leak-in-a-c-c-code or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720890/check-memory-leaks-in-windows.

Comment: You'll find many existing questions on this topic already.

Comment: Best tool for memory leak detection I've ever used was [Deleaker](http://www.deleaker.com/). Too bad it's not completely free.

Answer (score 3):

http://valgrind.org/

This is a good tool for Linux, can also be found on most distro's package-handler.

Comment: Actually, I need to check memory leak in an embedded system. IDE is HEW and we are using uCOSIII RTOS. Valigrind does nt support fr the above configurations. so can u pls suggest me a tool or a method to check memory leak

Answer (score 3):

Yes there it. Check out [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/). It can do lots of useful things, including detecting memory leaks.

Comment: Actually, I need to check memory leak in an embedded system. IDE is HEW and we are using uCOSIII RTOS. Valigrind does nt support fr the above configurations. so can u pls suggest me a tool are a method to check memory leak