# How to free memory used by a seq which used to store a contour in opencv 2.4.3

Tags: opencv

This code is used to capture from cam and then on each frame it convert it to HSV image then apply color segmentation on it to find the red, green and blue objects then it find the contour of each and store it in CVSeq.

the code is working well but the problem is that after 10 minutes it throws a run time exception that because no memory can allocate for the new contour although I use `cvClearMemStorage()` to release memory.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

CvSeq *contours;
IplImage* frame=0;
CvMemStorage* g_storage;

//This function threshold the HSV image and create a binary image
IplImage* GetThresholdedRedImage(IplImage* imgHSV)
{
       IplImage* imgThresh = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgHSV),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
       cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(160,160,60), cvScalar(180,256,256), imgThresh);

       //CvMemStorage* g_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
       cvFindContours( cvCloneImage(imgThresh), g_storage, &contours );
       if( contours )
       {
           cvDrawContours(frame, contours, cvScalar(0, 255, 0), cvScalarAll(255), 100);
           cvClearSeq(contours);

       }

       cvClearMemStorage(g_storage);

       return imgThresh;
}

IplImage* GetThresholdedGreenImage(IplImage* imgHSV)
{
       IplImage* imgThresh=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgHSV),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
       cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(38,160,60), cvScalar(75,256,256), imgThresh);

       //CvMemStorage* g_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
       cvFindContours( cvCloneImage(imgThresh), g_storage, &contours );
       if( contours )
       {
           cvDrawContours(frame, contours, cvScalar(0, 255, 255), cvScalarAll(255), 100);
           cvClearSeq(contours);
       }

       cvClearMemStorage(g_storage);

       return imgThresh;
}

IplImage* GetThresholdedBlueImage(IplImage* imgHSV)
{
       IplImage* imgThresh=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgHSV),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
       cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(75,160,60), cvScalar(130,256,256), imgThresh);

       //CvMemStorage* g_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
       cvFindContours( cvCloneImage(imgThresh), g_storage, &contours );
       if( contours )
       {
           cvDrawContours(frame, contours, cvScalarAll(255), cvScalarAll(255), 100);
           cvClearSeq(contours);
       }

       cvClearMemStorage(g_storage);

       return imgThresh;
}

int main()
{
      CvCapture* capture =0;

      capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
      if(!capture)
      {
        printf("Capture failure\n");
        return -1;
      }

      //IplImage* frame=0;

      cvNamedWindow("Video");
      cvNamedWindow("Red");
      //cvNamedWindow("Yellow");
      //cvNamedWindow("Orange");
      cvNamedWindow("Green");
      cvNamedWindow("Blue");
      //cvNamedWindow("Violet");
      g_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

      //iterate through each frames of the video
      while(true)
      {

            frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
            if(!frame) break;

            frame = cvCloneImage(frame);
            cvSmooth(frame, frame, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3); //smooth the original image using Gaussian kernel

            IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
            cvCvtColor(frame, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV); //Change the color format from BGR to HSV

            IplImage* redImgThresh = GetThresholdedRedImage(imgHSV);
            IplImage* blueImgThresh = GetThresholdedBlueImage(imgHSV);
            IplImage* greenImgThresh = GetThresholdedGreenImage(imgHSV);

            //cvClearSeq(contours);

            cvSmooth(redImgThresh, redImgThresh, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3); //smooth the binary image using Gaussian kernel
            cvSmooth(blueImgThresh, blueImgThresh, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3);
            cvSmooth(greenImgThresh, greenImgThresh, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3);

            cvShowImage("Red", redImgThresh);
            cvShowImage("blue", blueImgThresh);
            cvShowImage("green", greenImgThresh);
            cvShowImage("Video", frame);

            //Clean up used images
            cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
            cvReleaseImage(&redImgThresh);
            cvReleaseImage(&blueImgThresh);
            cvReleaseImage(&greenImgThresh);
            cvReleaseImage(&frame);

            //Wait 50mS
            int c = cvWaitKey(10);
            //If 'ESC' is pressed, break the loop
            if((char)c==27 ) break;
      }

      cvDestroyAllWindows() ;
      cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One part of your code I do not like is:

```
frame = cvCloneImage(frame);
...
cvReleaseImage(&frame);
```

Since, from `highgui.h`

```
 /* Just a combination of cvGrabFrame and cvRetrieveFrame
 !!!DO NOT RELEASE or MODIFY the retrieved frame!!!      */
 CVAPI(IplImage*) cvQueryFrame( CvCapture* capture );
```

I suggest using a different pointer to retrieve the image and cloning it to this one.

```
IplImage* tempFrame = cvCloneImage(frame);
frame = cvCloneImage(tempFrame);
...
cvReleaseImage(&frame);
```

Also, read: [OpenCV Introduction](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html)

See the **Working with video sequences** section.

Comment: that not relate to the problem but I try it and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

### ***If you are using MSVC to compile this...***

Include the following lines of code in the same file which contains your `main()` entry point:

```
#if _DEBUG
#   define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#   include <stdlib.h>
#   include <crtdbg.h>
#endif
```

Then, at the very top of your `main()` function, include the following:

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
```

What this will do is tell the VC runtime to dynamically monitor resource leaks in your application.
Compile and run your application, then quit it after a few seconds or so.

If you look at the output window, you should see some lines which look similar the following:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{18} normal block at 0x00780E80, 64 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
Object dump complete.
```

The point of interest here is `{18} normal block`, which is the memory allocation number and [block type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htdyz80k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Look at the first allocation number in the list, and copy it down.

Now, just under where you wrote `_CrtSetDbgFlag()` in your `main()` function, paste the following:

```
_CrtSetBreakAlloc(18); // Where `18` is the memory allocation number
```

If you compile and run again, your project should break at the point where that block of memory becomes allocated. If it breaks in an unknown section of code, you can check the Call Stack window to trace it back to the code you wrote.

You should use this information to know which objects need to be deallocated, and to give you an idea of approximately where to do so. Simply repeat this process until no further leaks have been detected.

All of this information and more can be found via [Memory Leak Detection and Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from the MSDN.

### ***If you are compiling for UNIX...***

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195220/tools-to-determine-memory-leak-in-a-c-c-code) for more information.

### ***Now, as far as HOW to deallocate goes...***

Well, that really depends on *what* has been allocated (and exactly how).
In the case of `CvSeq`, you typically shouldn't need to deallocate it at all, since this is (seemingly) managed by OpenCV until `cvReleaseMemStorage` is called. Since I don't see a call to this method anywhere within the code you've posted, it's possible that this is contributing to your resource leaks...

So I'd urge you to follow the steps above and figure out for yourself if the code breaks on `cvCreateMemStorage`. If it does, be sure to include a call to `cvReleaseMemStorage` once you are done using it.

On the other hand, `cvClearMemStorage` is [described](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/dynamic_structures.html) like so:
*"The function resets the top (free space boundary) of the storage to the very beginning. **This function does not deallocate any memory.** If the storage has a parent, the function returns all blocks to the parent."*

Is it possible you had these two functions confused?